# How to change the background of a toolbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How do I change the toolbar's background?

Comment: It would be convenient to know what kind of toolbar you are referring to.  Is this a toolbar in your GUI?  Is it Qt?  Java Swing?

Comment: Judging from the tags, I'd have to say it's a UIToolbar on the iPhone.

Comment: yes UIToolbar on the iPhone you should know from the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one common technique, which is a giant hack, but it seems to work. Subclass UIToolbar and override -drawRect: and just have that draw whatever you want. You can then create instances of the subclass whenever you need a toolbar, and if you have a toolbar in a xib file then you can just select it and change the class to whatever your subclass is.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just adjust the `tintColor` property? Or is changing the tint not good enough for your purposes?